# Impedindo que um atributo seja serializado ou deserializado

Tags: java, gson

Estou usando o Gson em um web service e preciso impedir que alguns atributos sejam serializados e outros que sejam impedidos de serem deserializados. Um dos motivos de impedir uma serialização é devido ao loop que se entra quando vai serializar um objeto que possui um relacionamento bidirecional com outro, gerando assim uma exception de `StackOverFlow`. Tem algum jeito de fazer isso ou terei que inserir null em um dos lados do relacionamento bidirecional pra impedir os erros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ExclusionStrategy**

Um dos caminhos para impedir que um atributo seja serializado é através da implementação de um `ExclusionStrategy`, onde através da reescrita do método `shouldSkipField()` informaremos se queremos ou não que um atributo de uma classe sendo serializada seja juntamente serializado, e o método `shouldSkipClass()`, onde o enfoque passa a ser a classe, se desejamos ou não que uma classe seja serializada.

```
class MeuGsonExclusionStrategy  implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
        return fieldAttributes.getName().equals("meuatributo");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.getName().equals("com.example.MinhaClasse");
    }
}
```

Após isso, basta na criação de nossa instância de Gson através do `GsonBuilder` invocarmos o método `addSerializationExclusionStrategy()`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new MeuGsonExclusionStrategy()).create();
```

Repare que também existe o método `addDeserializationExclusionStrategy()`, que possui o mesmo objeto mas para o processo de deserialização.

**excludeFieldsWithModifiers**

Um segundo método para impedirmos que um atributo seja serializado ou deserializado é o `excludeFieldsWithModifiers()` que espera como parâmetro um constante de `java.lang.reflect.Modifier`. Esse método informa quais campos queremos impedir informando seus modificadores. Por exemplo, caso não seja desejado que todos os atributos final sejam serializados ou deserializados, fazemos assim:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.FINAL).create();
```

**excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation**

Um terceiro método a ser comentado para essa função é o `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`, que impede que todos os atributos que não possuam a anotação `@Exposed` seja serializado ou deserializado. Ou seja, todos os campos que queremos que seja serializado ou deserializado deve ser anotado com `@Exposed`. Segue o exemplo de uso abaixo:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```